# How can I stop Aptana collapse all the codes by default?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

After upgraded aptana to 3.6 on mac, I meet a weird problem. That is: every time I open a new file, it shows correctly - for only 1 second, then it collapse all the codes automatically. This is so annoying so every time I open a new file I need to expand all and then start to coding.

Can someone tell me how to close this auto-collapse-all feature/bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called code folding, you can disable it from the preferences

It's enabled by default, but can be toggled in the language-specific editor settings.

Go to:

```
Preferences > Aptana Studio > Editors > [Language: PHP, Ruby, etc.]
```

In your specific language's editor deselect the 'Enable Folding' option